# Selectively use df.div() to divide only a certain column based on index match

Tags: python, pandas, division

I have 2 DataFrames, one is a monthly total and the other contains values by which I want to divide the first in order to get monthly percentage contributions.

Here are some example DataFrames:

```
MonthlyTotals = pd.DataFrame(data={'Month':[1,2,3],'Value':[100,200,300]})

Data = pd.DataFrame(data={'ID':[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3],
                          'Month':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],
                          'Value':[40,30,30,60,70,70,150,60,90]})
```

I am using `df.div()` so I set the index like so

```
MonthlyTotals.set_index('Month', inplace=True)
Data.set_index('Month', inplace=True)
```

Then I do the division

```
Contributions = Data.div(MonthlyTotals, axis='index')
```

The resulting DataFrame is what I want but I cannot see the `ID` that the `Value` relates to as this isn't in the `MonthlyTotals` frame. How would I use `df.div()` but only selectively on certain columns?

Here is an example dataframe of the result I am looking for

```
result = pd.DataFrame(data={'ID':[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3],'Value':[0.4,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.35,0.35,0.5,0.2,0.3]})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not need MonthlyTotals if Data is complete. You can calculate MonthlyTotal using `transform` and then calculate Contributions.

```
Data = pd.DataFrame(data={'ID':[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3],
                          'Month':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],
                          'Value':[40,30,30,60,70,70,150,60,90]})
Data['MonthlyTotal'] = Data.Gropuby('Month')['Value'].transform('sum')
Data['Contributions'] = Data['Value'] / Data['MonthlyTotal']
```

Output

```
   ID  Month  Value  MonthlyTotal  Contributions
0   1      1     40           100           0.40
1   2      1     30           100           0.30
2   3      1     30           100           0.30
3   1      2     60           200           0.30
4   2      2     70           200           0.35
5   3      2     70           200           0.35
6   1      3    150           300           0.50
7   2      3     60           300           0.20
8   3      3     90           300           0.30
```

Answer (score 1):

Also if you would like only use pandas you can fix your code with `reindex` + `update`

```
Data.update(Data['Value'].div(MonthlyTotals['Value'].reindex(Data.index),axis=0))
Data
       ID  Value
Month           
1       1   0.40
1       2   0.30
1       3   0.30
2       1   0.30
2       2   0.35
2       3   0.35
3       1   0.50
3       2   0.20
3       3   0.30
```

Comment: Here you have divided the ID by (?). What I am looking for is the ID that the value relates to. I have updated my question with an example results dataframe.

Comment: That's the badger!